# wpf width issues with listview in listviewitem

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem, expander

I have a listview in which I have several listviewitems but I want to show additional information, therefore I added a expander which shows another listview within said listviewitem. But my problem is that the listview is only as wide as the listviews column width.

**XAML**

```
<ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Expander>
                                <ListView>
                                    <ListView.View>
                                        <GridView>
                                            <GridViewColumn Header="Order number" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
                                            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                                            <GridViewColumn Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}"/>
                                        </GridView>
                                    </ListView.View>
                                </ListView>
                            </Expander>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Order number" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding OrderNumber}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Customer" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Customer}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Total Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CombinedPrice}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Urgency" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Urgency}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because the expander is within the cell in the listview and that cell will constrain it's size.

It will not expand to the size of it's content because ListView columns do not dynamically resize.

You could consider using a togglebutton and popup instead.  Bind the isopen of the popup to the togglebutton ischecked.

A popup is a separate window effectively and hence not inside that "box" around the cell.

You could alternatively consider a datagrid which has rowdetails expand out below a row.

https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/